# How to not get regular price to show if sale price = regular price

Tags: javascript, if-statement, isnull

I created a dynamic template to populate products with pricing pulled directly from the catalog. However, when a particular product is not on sale, there is still strikethrough pricing with the regular price even though they are both the same. I initially created two variables, if they equal each other, to set the regularPrice = null. However that is not working. I am new to javascript and help would be appreciated!

strikethrough pricing:

my code:

```
const regularPrice = document.querySelector("span.pr__price--inactive").textContent;
const salePrice = document.querySelector("span.pr__price--active").textContent;
if (regularPrice === salePrice){
    regularPrice === null;
}
```

markup:

```
    {{#if attributes.price.value}}
    <p class="pr__price">
       <span class="pr__price--active">
         <span data-locale="en_US" data-currencycode="USD">$</span> 
         {{attributes.price.value}}
       </span>

       {{#if attributes.listPrice.value}}
       <span class="pr__price--inactive">
         <span data-locale="en_US" data-currencycode="USD">$</span> 
         {{attributes.listPrice.value}}
       </span>
       {{/if}}
    </p>
```

Comment: It appears you're not telling your whole story. Is there a templating library involved?  i.e., for processing `{{#if attributes.price.value}}`? Furthermore, note that you are not setting the _display value_ of `regularPrice` to null. You're only attempting to set the _variable_ (the handle to the UI content) to null.  Annddd.... `===` is for equality comparison, not value assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting values from your UI for comparison-- particularly if you have access to the raw data you're pulling-- is less than ideal. So I'll start by saying this is probably not a great approach.

However, I'll attempt to answer your question since you're missing a few important points.

1. Your version of the code is potentially going to change the value of `regularPrice`.  Don't make it a `const` if it might change!
2. `===` is for strict equality comparison, not assignment. You're trying to use it for assignment.
3. Are you certain your page won't have multiple instances of `span.pr__price--inactive` and `span.pr__price--active`?  Using IDs here would allow you to be specific.
4. `textContent` will return text. That's what you're attempting to compare. Shall we convert that to numeric value?

```js
let regularPriceElement = document.querySelector("span.pr__price--inactive"); //this is a handle to the HTML element
let regularPrice = regularPriceElement.textContent; //this is a snapshot of the value in that element
let salePrice = document.querySelector("span.pr__price--active").textContent;
regularPrice = +regularPrice; //convert to a number
salePrice = +salePrice; //convert to a number
console.log(regularPrice, salePrice, regularPrice === salePrice);

if (regularPrice === salePrice){
    regularPriceElement.textContent = "(blank)"; //blank out the element content
    //or add strike-through
    regularPriceElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="pr__price--active">1.99</span>
</div>

<div>
<span class="pr__price--inactive">1.99</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth checking which will be getting to the code before checking if they are equal. log them using console.log() or use a debugger. Also using the query selector the first element of your class will be returned but you need to parse it using parseInt or parseDouble beforehand to make the comparison.